How do I get rid of the white borders?
<center>
<button onclick="openGame()" style="background-color: #0047AB; color: #fff; border: 1; border-color: #0047AB; vertical-align: center; font-size: 26px; width:100%;      cursor: pointer; border-radius: 10px;"> "Minecraft"Fullscreen </button>
<script>
function openGame() {
var win = window.open ()
var url = "https://eaglercraft.com/mc/1.5.2/"
var iframe = win.document.createElement('iframe')
iframe.style.width = "100%"
iframe.style.height = "100%"
iframe.style.border = "none"
iframe.src = url
win.document.body.appendChild(iframe)
}
</script>
</center>

Here is the code. The iframe width and height say 100% and the border says none, yet the white borders still appear after you click the button. It's really frustrating.
